# MySQL Shared key over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, key

I am trying to optimize my query, and I think I need to add a combined key to two `date` fields that reside within three different tables.

The tables:

`playerjoins` and `playerleaves`:

```
+------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+------------------+
|  "Field"   |   "Type"   | "Null" | "Key" | "Default" |     "Extra"      |
+------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+------------------+
| "id"       | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "PRI" | \N        | "auto_increment" |
| "globalId" | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
| "date"     | "datetime" | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
| "serverId" | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
| "playerId" | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
+------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+------------------+
```

`levelsloaded`:

```
+--------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+------------------+
|   "Field"    |   "Type"   | "Null" | "Key" | "Default" |     "Extra"      |
+--------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+------------------+
| "id"         | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "PRI" | \N        | "auto_increment" |
| "globalId"   | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
| "date"       | "datetime" | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
| "serverId"   | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
| "gamemodeId" | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
| "mapId"      | "int(11)"  | "NO"   | "MUL" | \N        | ""               |
+--------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+------------------+
```

MySQL query:

```
SELECT llbelow.id, llbelow.globalId, llbelow.date, llbelow.serverId, llbelow.gamemodeId, llbelow.mapId
FROM (
    SELECT ll.id, ll.globalId, ll.date, ll.serverId, ll.gamemodeId, ll.mapId, pjl.origin, pjl.date AS pjldate 
    FROM 
    (
        (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerjoins' AS origin
        FROM playerjoins pj WHERE playerId = 2224)
    UNION ALL
        (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerleaves' AS origin
        FROM playerleaves pl WHERE playerId = 2224)
    )
    pjl
    JOIN levelsloaded ll
    ON pjl.date <= ll.date
) llbelow
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ll.id, ll.globalId, pjl.date AS pjldate  
    FROM 
    (
        (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerjoins' AS origin
        FROM playerjoins pj WHERE playerId = 2224)
    UNION ALL
        (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerleaves' AS origin
        FROM playerleaves pl WHERE playerId = 2224)
    )
    pjl
    JOIN levelsloaded ll
    ON pjl.date <= ll.date
) llbelow_inner
ON llbelow.id = llbelow_inner.id AND (llbelow.pjldate < llbelow_inner.pjldate OR (llbelow.pjldate = llbelow_inner.pjldate AND llbelow.globalId < llbelow_inner.globalId))
WHERE llbelow_inner.id IS NULL AND origin = 'playerjoins'
ORDER BY llbelow.date DESC, llbelow.pjldate DESC
```

The `DESCRIBE` of the query:

```
+------+----------------+--------------+--------+-----------------+------------+-----------+-------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
| "id" | "select_type"  |   "table"    | "type" | "possible_keys" |   "key"    | "key_len" | "ref" | "rows"  | "filtered" |                    "Extra"                     |
+------+----------------+--------------+--------+-----------------+------------+-----------+-------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
| "1"  | "PRIMARY"      | "<derived2>" | "ALL"  | \N              | \N         | \N        | \N    | "74494" | "100,00"   | "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" |
| "1"  | "PRIMARY"      | "<derived5>" | "ALL"  | \N              | \N         | \N        | \N    | "74494" | "100,00"   | "Using where; Not exists"                      |
| "5"  | "DERIVED"      | "<derived6>" | "ALL"  | \N              | \N         | \N        | \N    | "92"    | "100,00"   | ""                                             |
| "5"  | "DERIVED"      | "ll"         | "ALL"  | "date"          | \N         | \N        | \N    | "1578"  | "100,00"   | "Using where; Using join buffer"               |
| "6"  | "DERIVED"      | "pj"         | "ref"  | "playerId"      | "playerId" | "4"       | ""    | "52"    | "100,00"   | ""                                             |
| "7"  | "UNION"        | "pl"         | "ref"  | "playerId"      | "playerId" | "4"       | ""    | "40"    | "100,00"   | ""                                             |
| \N   | "UNION RESULT" | "<union6,7>" | "ALL"  | \N              | \N         | \N        | \N    | \N      | \N         | ""                                             |
| "2"  | "DERIVED"      | "<derived3>" | "ALL"  | \N              | \N         | \N        | \N    | "92"    | "100,00"   | ""                                             |
| "2"  | "DERIVED"      | "ll"         | "ALL"  | "date"          | \N         | \N        | \N    | "1578"  | "100,00"   | "Using where; Using join buffer"               |
| "3"  | "DERIVED"      | "pj"         | "ref"  | "playerId"      | "playerId" | "4"       | ""    | "52"    | "100,00"   | ""                                             |
| "4"  | "UNION"        | "pl"         | "ref"  | "playerId"      | "playerId" | "4"       | ""    | "40"    | "100,00"   | ""                                             |
| \N   | "UNION RESULT" | "<union3,4>" | "ALL"  | \N              | \N         | \N        | \N    | \N      | \N         | ""                                             |
+------+----------------+--------------+--------+-----------------+------------+-----------+-------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

What would I need to do to optimize the query?

**EDIT:** Added a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb702/2 with example data. What I want is the following, for people interesting in rebuilding the query, informally spoken:

- This database is stores information out of log files from a FPS shooter game.
- A player can join or leave the server.
- The server will load a map every 15-30 minutes averagely.
- I want to show, in a personal log about player x, only the maps in which he was actually playing.

More formally said: I want all rows from `levelsloaded` for which the last action (join/leave) the player did before the level was loaded, was joining the server.
(Note: This is just one way of formalizing the query, there is no need to stick to it)

Output data I want for the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb702/1

Also, importantly, the query needs to be **fast**. It should be able to be used live, so I am aiming for a response time of under 100ms indepedent of the database size.
As you can see, I did use a working query to provide the output data I want, however that query runs in 96 seconds on the live database, and even still 2 seconds if I get rid of the union between `playerjoins` and `playerleaves`.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do?  There may be a better way to formulate your query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am trying to return all level loads for which the last action (joining or leaving) the player did, was joining.

Comment: . . If you provide sample data and desired results, you will do a better of explaining what you are trying to do.  I believe there is a way to write your query differently so it will be more efficient.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll post it as soon as I have time, just an hour for it I guess. I'm though deeply considering to either let the application do more work before inserting into the database (not easy though), or switch to MariaDB or something.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added the sample data and desired as per request. Hopefully at least someone will take a look at it, as it took me quite some time now to get the question details together.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you combine the tables `playerjoins` and `playerleaves`:

```
CREATE TABLE `playeraction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `globalId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `serverId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `playerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `action` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'J',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `globalId` (`globalId`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `serverId` (`serverId`),
  KEY `playerId` (`playerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then replace:

```
    SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerjoins' AS origin
    FROM playerjoins pj WHERE playerId = 1)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, 'playerleaves' AS origin
    FROM playerleaves pl WHERE playerId = 1)
```

with

```
    SELECT id, globalId, date, serverId, playerId, action FROM playeraction
```

and your query is now much shorter:

```
SELECT llbelow.id, llbelow.globalId, llbelow.date, llbelow.serverId,
       llbelow.gamemodeId, llbelow.mapId
FROM (
    SELECT ll.id, ll.globalId, ll.date, ll.serverId, ll.gamemodeId,
           ll.mapId, pjl.action, pjl.date AS pjldate 
      FROM playeraction pjl
      JOIN levelsloaded ll ON pjl.date <= ll.date
     WHERE playerId = 2224
) llbelow
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ll.id, ll.globalId, pjl.date AS pjldate  
      FROM playeraction pjl
      JOIN levelsloaded ll ON pjl.date <= ll.date
     WHERE playerId = 2224
) llbelow_inner
ON llbelow.id = llbelow_inner.id
   AND (llbelow.pjldate < llbelow_inner.pjldate
        OR (llbelow.pjldate = llbelow_inner.pjldate
            AND llbelow.globalId < llbelow_inner.globalId))
WHERE llbelow_inner.id IS NULL AND llbelow.action = 'J'
ORDER BY llbelow.date DESC, llbelow.pjldate DESC
```

We can simplify it more, if necessary.